# Flutter - XCode 14.3 - Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, cocoapods

I'm spending the second day on solving this problem. I found many solutions to this problem, but none of them helped me.
Below I will provide what I tried and it did NOT help -

added "-f" flag  `source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`

changed podfile to

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
         end
    end
  end
end
```

Tried checking the box "Run script only on installation"

Tried

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Clean build of Xcode

Tried  `sudo gem update cocoapods`

I will be glad for any help